# QT Creator - QHBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt

В документации по `qt`, нашел `QHBoxLayout`, которая выставляет кнопки рядом с друг другом.

```
QWidget *window = new QWidget;
QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("One");
QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Two");
QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("Three");
QPushButton *button4 = new QPushButton("Four");
QPushButton *button5 = new QPushButton("Five");

QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(button1);
layout->addWidget(button2);
layout->addWidget(button3);
layout->addWidget(button4);
layout->addWidget(button5);

window->setLayout(layout);
window->show();
```

как разделить к примеру кнопки:
В одной строке 1, 2, 3, а во второй 4 и 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
QVBoxLayout *line1 = new QVBoxLayout;
QVBoxLayout *line2 = new QVBoxLayout;
line1->addWidget(button1);
line1->addWidget(button2);
line1->addWidget(button3);
line2->addWidget(button4);
line2->addWidget(button5);
layout->addLayout(line1);
layout->addLayout(line2);
window->setLayout(layout);
```